# Running HQL query in console

Tags: intellij-idea, hql

I am trying to run the following query in IntelliJ:

```java
@Query(value = "" +
        "SELECT offer FROM OfferEntity offer " +
        "   JOIN offer.placeOwnership AS owner " +
        "   JOIN owner.place AS place " +
        "WHERE " +
        "   place.id = :placeId AND " +
        "   offer.dayFrom = :offerDate AND " +
        "   offer.repeating = false")
```

as I am doing so, I get ask to provide the parameters `placeId` and `offerDate`. My problem is I have no idea about the latter.

[image]

I have no idea how I can run this query.

---

I also tried to run it manually inside the console like this:

```sql
SELECT offer FROM OfferEntity offer 
   JOIN offer.placeOwnership AS owner 
   JOIN owner.place AS place 
WHERE 
   place.id = 1L AND 
   offer.dayFrom = java.time.LocalDate.parse("2018-10-08") AND 
   offer.repeating = false
```

but that gives my a syntax error.

Comment: Have your tried to run your query only for place.id = 1L and check if goes in error?

Comment: Check this site: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/hibernate-console-tool-window.html

Comment: @JoeTaras Yes I did - I think the problem is that `JOIN` is not working for me at all [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726751/cannot-query-entities-using-join).