# Cannot query entities using JOIN

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, hql

I am trying to get my head around *HQL* and run it inside the Persistence window of IntelliJ IDEA.

Here's the thing: I can run simple queries like these:

```
hql> SELECT offer FROM OfferEntit offer;
hql> SELECT offer FROM OfferEntit offer WHERE offer.id = 1L;
```

but if I add something like a `JOIN`:

```
hql> SELECT offer FROM OfferEntit offer 
     JOIN offer.owner AS owner WHERE owner.id = 1L;
```

I get an empty result. Always. No matter what I do. I have no idea why..

---

Also

- I checked whether those records exist - yes they do
- I do not get any error logs

Comment: Try removing `AS`

Comment: @ObiWan-PallavJha Why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with left join or join fetch

```
SELECT offer FROM OfferEntit offer 
 LEFT JOIN offer.owner AS owner WHERE owner.id = 1L
```

---

```
SELECT offer FROM OfferEntit offer 
 JOIN FETCH offer.owner AS owner WHERE owner.id = 1L
```

Comment: Still the same result. This code is working at runtime. It's just not working in the console.